# How to create or delete multiple data together with ngrx?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

In conjunction with all the **"flux architecture"** (`actions`, `effects`, `reducers` etc ...) and `rxjs` I am trying to **create and or delete multiple data**.

**And I have the following problems:**

1. How to create or delete multiple data both in the backend and in
   entities in the state?
2. I've been researching and people said to use forkJoin, but how is it
   used with flux architecture?
3. How to receive this data in real time and make other requests wait
   for them to arrive?

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

**BACKEND SERVICE:**

```
create(peoples: Array<IPeople>): Observable<Array<IPeople>> {
        const https = [];
        peoples.forEach((people) => https.push(this.httpClient.post<IPeople>(this.endpoint, people)));
        return forkJoin([]);
    }
```

**EFFECTS**

```
createAll$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(fromPeopleActions.CREATE),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            return this.backend.create(action.people).pipe(
                map((people) => fromPeopleActions.CREATE_SUCCESS({ people })),
                catchError((error) => of(fromPeopleActions.CREATE_FAIL({ error: this.requestHandler.getError(error) })))
            );
        })
    )
);
```

**REDUCER:**

```
const peopleReducer = createReducer(
    INIT_STATE,
    on(fromPeopleAction.GET_ALL_SUCCESS, fromPeopleAction.CREATE_SUCCESS, fromPeopleAction.DELETE_SUCCESS, (state, { peoples }) => adapter.addMany(peoples, { ...state, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.GET_ALL_FAIL, fromPeopleAction.CREATE_FAIL, fromPeopleAction.DELETE_FAIL, (state, { error }) => ({ ...state, error, loading: false }))
);
```

**CALL**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.peopleDispatchService.getAll();
    this.peopleSelectorsService.loading.subscribe((isLoading) => {
        if (!isLoading) {
            this.peopleSelectorsService.total.subscribe((total) => {
                console.log(total);
                if (total === 0) {
                    this.peopleDispatchService.create([
                        { id: '0', isMain: true, name: 'THIAGO DE BONIS CARVALHO SAAD SAUD', avatar: 'assets/users/thiagobonis.jpg', messages: null },
                        { id: '1', isMain: false, name: 'BILL GATES', avatar: 'assets/users/billgates.jpg', messages: null },
                        { id: '2', isMain: false, name: 'STEVE JOBS', avatar: 'assets/users/stevejobs.jpg', messages: null },
                        { id: '3', isMain: false, name: 'LINUS TORVALDS', avatar: 'assets/users/linustorvalds.jpg', messages: null },
                        { id: '4', isMain: false, name: 'EDSGER DIJKSTRA', avatar: 'assets/users/dijkstra.jpg', messages: null },
                    ])
                } else {
                    this.peopleSelectorsService.allIds.subscribe((ids) => this.peopleDispatchService.delete(ids.toString()));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it almost right

```js
create(people: Array<IPeople>): Observable<Array<IPeople>> {
  return forkJoin(
    ...people.map(person => this.httpClient.post<IPeople>(this.endpoint, person)),
  );
}
```

Also `fromPeopleAction.DELETE_SUCCESS` and `addMany` sound strange together. I would add an independent `on` for it.

now create will cause the creation requests.

*How to create or delete multiple data both in the backend and in entities in the state?*

- the way you do is fine.

*I've been researching and people said to use forkJoin, but how is it used with flux architecture?*

- check my example above

*How to receive this data in real time and make other requests wait for them to arrive?*

- better would be to have a single request to fetch all data and then transform the response to a lot of actions like ADD_MANY etc. Or to use `forkJoin` if your backend doesn't provide single endpoints for bulk data exchange.